# A geometry olympiad problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Given two circles and three straight lines, every single line intersects the circles in chords of different lengths. The intersection points of the straight lines will create a triangle. Prove that the circumcircle of the triangle passes through the segment joining the two circle centers.

This was a problem on a Russian Olympiad from 2008 and I have no idea even where to start. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you have the original Russian text? Some of the translation is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Hm no, my friend translated it who is now out of state. Is the intersection ambiguous?

Comment: you may try to prove that the distance between the center of one of the circle and the center of the circumcircle is less than the radius of the circumcircle, and the distance from the center of the other circle to the center of the circumcircle is greater that the radius of the circumcircle.

Comment: any way, is there any information about the relation between the two circles? do they intersect? do the have the same radius?